# Django modelformset is_valid method retrieves entire model from database

Tags: django, django-forms, formset

I have a modelformset when is_valid method is called the entire model objects of the underlying form is retrieved from the database which is not efficient if the database table contains hundred of thousands records, I believe Django was not designed with this deficiency and there must be something wrong with my code, When is_valid is called these queries are sent to the database, the first query has no WHERE clause which means it will retrieve the entire table!:

```
[{'sql': 'SELECT @@SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL', 'time': '0.000'},
{'sql': 'SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED', 'time': '0.000'},

**{'sql': 'SELECT `npr`.`rid`, `npr`.`PID`, `npr`.`rel`, `npr`.`CID` FROM `npr` ORDER BY `npr`.`rid` ASC', 'time': '0.037'}**

{'sql': 'SELECT `person_details`.`ID`, `person_details`.`firstName` FROM `person_details` WHERE `person_details`.`ID` = 198 LIMIT 21', 'time': '0.001'},
{'sql': 'SELECT `person_details`.`ID`, `person_details`.`firstName` FROM `person_details` WHERE `person_details`.`ID` = 1243 LIMIT 21', 'time': '0.000'},
{'sql': 'SELECT `npr`.`rid`, `npr`.`PID`, `npr`.`rel`, `npr`.`CID` FROM `npr` WHERE `npr`.`rid` = 1377 LIMIT 21', 'time': '0.000'},
{'sql': 'SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `person_details` WHERE `person_details`.`ID` = 198 LIMIT 1', 'time': '0.000'},
{'sql': 'SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `person_details` WHERE `person_details`.`ID` = 1243 LIMIT 1', 'time': '0.000'},
{'sql': 'SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `npr` WHERE (`npr`.`CID` = 1243 AND `npr`.`PID` = 198 AND NOT (`npr`.`rid` = 1377)) LIMIT 1', 'time': '0.000'},
{'sql': 'SELECT `person_details`.`ID`, `person_details`.`firstName` FROM `person_details` WHERE `person_details`.`ID` = 200 LIMIT 21', 'time': '0.000'},
{'sql': 'SELECT `person_details`.`ID`, `person_details`.`firstName` FROM `person_details` WHERE `person_details`.`ID` = 1243 LIMIT 21', 'time': '0.004'},
{'sql': 'SELECT `npr`.`rid`, `npr`.`PID`, `npr`.`rel`, `npr`.`CID` FROM `npr` WHERE `npr`.`rid` = 1378 LIMIT 21', 'time': '0.000'},
{'sql': 'SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `person_details` WHERE `person_details`.`ID` = 200 LIMIT 1', 'time': '0.000'},
{'sql': 'SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `person_details` WHERE `person_details`.`ID` = 1243 LIMIT 1', 'time': '0.000'},
{'sql': 'SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `npr` WHERE (`npr`.`CID` = 1243 AND `npr`.`PID` = 200 AND NOT (`npr`.`rid` = 1378)) LIMIT 1', 'time': '0.000'}]
```

The models

```
   class PersonDetails(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
        firstname = models.CharField(db_column='firstName', max_length=20)
    
        class Meta:
            managed = True
            db_table = 'person_details'
    
    
    class Npr(models.Model):
        rid = models.AutoField(db_column='rid', primary_key=True)
        pid = models.ForeignKey(PersonDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='PID', related_name='pid')
        rel = models.CharField(max_length=1)
        cid = models.ForeignKey(PersonDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='CID', related_name='cid')
    
        class Meta:
            managed = True
            db_table = 'npr'
            unique_together = (('pid', 'cid'),)
```

and Form definition:

```
class prelation(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Npr
        fields = ['pid', 'rel', 'cid']
        widgets = {'pid':HiddenInput(), 'rel':HiddenInput(), 'cid':HiddenInput()}

prelations = modelformset_factory(Npr, form = prelation, can_delete=True, extra=1)
```

How to optimize the queries sent to database when is_valid method is called against a modelformset? I am using Django Version: 3.0.4, Python version: 3.7.3, Database: 10.3.22-MariaDB-0+deb10u1-log

**Edit 1:**
I am using the Django shell to test because I want to make the question concise and avoid the complexities of the full application and both gave the same results.

```
>>> from tstapp.forms import prelations
>>> 
>>> 
>>> datana={'form-TOTAL_FORMS':'2',
... 'form-INITIAL_FORMS':'2',
... 'form-MIN_NUM_FORMS':'0',
... 'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS':'1000',
... 'form-0-pid':'198',
... 'form-0-rel':'F',
... 'form-0-cid':'1243',
... 'form-0-rid':'1377',
... 'form-0-DELETE':'None',
... 'form-1-pid':'200',
... 'form-1-rel':'M',
... 'form-1-cid':'1243',
... 'form-1-rid':'1378',
... 'form-1-DELETE':'None'}
>>> 
>>> form=prelations(data=datana)
>>> connection.queries
[]
>>> form.is_valid()
True
>>> connection.queries
[{'sql': 'SELECT @@SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL', 'time': '0.000'}, {'sql': 'SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED', 'time': '0.000'}, {'sql': 'SELECT `npr`.`rid`, `npr`.`PID`, `npr`.`rel`, `npr`.`CID` FROM `npr` ORDER BY `npr`.`rid` ASC', 'time': '0.037'}, {'sql': '
```

Comment: Add your view or the code that is calling is_valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately; I found the missing part, in documentation it say ([Changing the queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset)):

> By default, when you create a formset from a model, the formset will
> use a queryset that includes all objects in the model (e.g.,
> Author.objects.all()). You can override this behavior by using the
> queryset argument:

I was not changing changing the queryset before validating the formset which caused Django to retrieve the entire underlying model and include all objects in the model. I should have used the same queryset used to generate the formset in creating the form that will be validated. The validation should go like this:

```
qs = prs.objects.filter(Q(cid = 1243) | Q(pid = 1243))
form=prelations(data=datana, queryset = qs)
```